# 'CSS display: none' will work just fine, but 'document.body.removeChild(child);' will break my code

Tags: javascript

people that love programming.

Before I explain my issue, I need you to understand what I am doing here. It is a very simple game.

Do you remember that console video game "Guitar Hero"? Or if you are a little younger, "Piano Tiles"?

If you don't know what I'm talking about, click on this link to get an idea of what it is = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWLKlEg0VMs&ab_channel=MattSterner

Well, that is exactly what I am doing with this website (on a more basic level of course).

In other words, there are musical notes falling from the top and the player has to press a button when that note hits the bottom of the screen.

Finally, what is my issue?

Well, when the note gets to the button, I am able to recognize it, which was actually hard and took me quite a while. And when I recognize it (inside the `for loop` below), and when I press the key E or keycode 69, the note disappears, which is exactly what I want.

So what's wrong?

Well, as you can see, I am setting the div's display property to `none` but the div is not actually being eliminated, this results in every div/musical note in the game to accumulate at the bottom with a display property of `none`, making the game slow.

So what do I want?

I want the div/musical note to be eliminated from the website entirely, gone, finito... not just setting its display property to `none`.

So what have I tried myself?

I tried `document.body.removeChild(child)` but this actually broke the game, notes stopped coming from the top, so it was not a fix (I have no clue of why this happened by the way).

You can see the part of the code I am having trouble with here:

```
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    if (event.keyCode === 69 /* E */) {
        for (let i = 0; i < leftSquares.length; i++){
            if (leftSquares[i].style.top > "740.5px" && leftSquares[i].style.top < "790.5px"){
                console.log('correctin');
                leftSquares[i].style.display = "none";
                // document.body.removeChild(leftSquares[i]);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Or you can play around with the full game here: https://codepen.io/xavi-font/pen/MWeRdwr

Sticks and stones won't break my code, but `document.body.removeChild(child)` does (for a reason I don't know).

Comment: I tried your codepen. When I press `e` the squares are not hidden. Is this expected? also, the game slows down even when no key is pressed.

Comment: I see, the squares dont hide because the screen in codepen is so small, and I did the game to fit my screen (I will later fix it to be responsive). the game slows down when keys are or are not pressed because they all accumulate in the bottom of the screen and keep falling infinitely (which is the issue I wanna solve)

Comment: @sample that message was for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing `document.body.removeChild(leftSquares[i]);`

You remove the element from the page (DOM), but you do not remove the id from `idArray = [];`

So on the next loop of your code you get to:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    let element = document.getElementById(i.toString());
    animateFunction(element);
}
```

and now the element does not exist, so you can't animate it, and you get an error that breaks the game.

A simple solution (not necessarily the best) could be:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {
    let element = document.getElementById(i.toString());
    if (element) {
      animateFunction(element);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to keep specific id's in the array `idArray`, then when you delete an element, remove it's *ID* from the array, and where you previously have `for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) {` you can now use

```
idArray.forEach((id) => {
  let element = document.getElementById(id.toString());
...
});
```

---

Your game also slows down, and if you `console.log` the `element.style.top` from within **animateFunction** you will see that if you don't press E at the correct time, then the element just keeps animating down the page forever.

So I would also suggest a garbage collect function within the **animateFunction**

maybe something like this?

```js
function animateFunction(element) { 
    if (element.style.top == "-100px") {
        const interval = setInterval(function() {
            element.style.top = eval(parseInt(element.style.top) + 1).toString() + "px";
            let currentNotePosition = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            // Garbage Collect
            if (currentNotePosition.top > window.innerHeight) {
              document.body.removeChild(element);
            }
        }, speed);
    }
}
```